# Oracle db connection across all the oracle server from 11g on wards to 19c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle18c, oracle19c

In my current project, facing problem of connecting the oracle server from oracle client. Here are the details

Oracle Server 12.2.0.1 64-bit
Oracle Client 12.2.0.1 32-bit

But after analysis, I noticed that I have a common requirement to connect all the oracle servers e.g. 11g, 12c, 18c, 19c from any of the oracle client.

I tried to find common version of oracle.dataaccess.dll which will work for all the above oracle servers from any of the oracle clients. But I couldn't able to find. For example 4.122.19.1 works for all the servers only if client is 19c. For 12c client, it's not working and so on. Is there any common version of oracle.dataaccess.dll available to serve this purpose?

Or do I need to use some other assembly in my project?

I also tried to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll. But it has an issue of locating the tnsnames.ora.

Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.